# Can not use hidden commandButton with @RequestScoped backing-bean

Tags: jsf-2

I have following sample code.
Initially, only commandButton **Two** is visible. When I click this button, commandButton **One** is also visible. But when I click **One**, the backing-bean method **click1** does not get fired.

Following is my code:

**xhtml**

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:inputHidden id="show" value="#{bean.show1}" />
    <h:commandButton id="button1" value="One" action="#{bean.click1}"
        rendered="#{bean.show1}" />
</h:form>
<h:form id="form2">
    <h:inputHidden id="show" value="#{bean.show1}" />
    <h:commandButton id="button2" value="Two" action="#{bean.click2}" />
</h:form>
```

**backing-bean**

```
@RequestScoped
@Named("bean")
public class JsfTrial implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2784462583813130092L;

    private boolean show1; // + getter, setter

    public String click1() {
        System.out.println("Click1()");
        return null;
    }

    public String click2() {
        System.out.println("Click2()");
        setShow1(true);
        return null;
    }

}
```

I found a very informative answer by BalusC.

- [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-is-not-being-invoked)

If I understand it correctly, my problem is due to **point 5** of this answer.

Does that also mean we can not use hidden commandButton with **@RequestScoped** backing-bean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the request scope, you should only pass the condition as a request parameter to the subsequent requests by `<f:param>` instead of by a JSF hidden input field `<h:inputHidden>`. The value of the hidden input field is only set in the model during Update Model Values phase, while the condition of the `rendered` attribute is already evaluated during Apply Request Values phase which is earlier.

So, use `<f:param>` instead of `<h:inputHidden>`:

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:commandButton id="button1" value="One" action="#{bean.click1}"
        rendered="#{bean.show1}">
        <f:param name="show1" value="#{bean.show1}" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:form id="form2">
    <h:commandButton id="button2" value="Two" action="#{bean.click2}">
        <f:param name="show1" value="#{bean.show1}" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

This way you can extract them as request parameter in bean's (post)constructor.

```
public JsfTrial() {
    String show1 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("show1");
    this.show1 = (show1 != null) && Boolean.valueOf(show1);
}
```

Ugly, but CDI doesn't offer a builtin annotation which substituties JSF's `@ManagedProperty("#{param.show1}")`. You could however [homegrow](http://www.glxn.net/?p=141) such an annotation.